# Newton's Gradient Descent Linear Regression

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, linear-regression, newtons-method, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement a function in MatLab that calculates the optimum linear regression using Newton's method. 
However, I became stuck in one point. I don't know how to find the second derivative. So I cannot implement it. Here is my code.

Thanks for your help.

```
function [costs,thetas] = mod_gd_linear_reg(x,y,numofit)

    theta=zeros(1,2);
    o=ones(size(x));
    x=[x,o]';
    for i=1:numofit

        err=(x.'*theta.')-y;
        delta=(x * err) / length(y); %% first derivative
        delta2; %% second derivative

        theta = theta - (delta./delta2).';

        costs(i)=cost(x,y,theta);
        thetas(i,:)=theta;


    end

end
function totCost = cost(x,y,theta)

 totCost=sum(((x.'*theta.')-y).*((x.'*theta.')-y)) / 2*length(y);

end
```

Edit::

I solved this issue with some paper and pen. All you need is some calculus and matrix operations. I found the second derivative and it is working now. I am sharing my working code for those who are interested.

```
function [costs,thetas] = mod_gd_linear_reg(x,y,numofit)

theta=zeros(1,2);
sos=0;
for i=1:size(x)
    sos=sos+(x(i)^2);
end
sumx=sum(x);
o=ones(size(x));
x=[x,o]';
for i=1:numofit

    err=(x.'*theta.')-y;
    delta=(x * err) / length(y); %% first derivative
   delta2=2*[sos,1;1,sumx];  %% second derivative

    theta = theta - (delta.'*length(y)/delta2);

    costs(i)=cost(x,y,theta);
    thetas(i,:)=theta;


end

end

function totCost = cost(x,y,theta)

 totCost=sum(((x.'*theta.')-y).*((x.'*theta.')-y)) / 2*length(y);

end
```

Answer (score 2):

It is known that second derivative may be difficult to find.

This [note page 6](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350/lectures/26/lecture-26.pdf) might be helpful in some sense.

If you find full newton's method difficult, you can use some other functions like `fminunc` and `fmincg`.